# installing laravel app on addon domain with shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I've searched up and down and while there are a lot of the same solutions out there that show how to do this, none of them seem to be working (surely, I having something configured wrong here).

I am trying to deploy a laravel app on an addon domain with shared hosting.

I have uploaded my app (all but the public folder) along side the public_html folder (same level, not inside it).

Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee4p5.jpg

I've taken everything from the public folder and put it inside a folder on the addon domain.

Ex.: public_html/mysite.com/laravel/

Note that I've substituted my actual username and domain with placeholders here (obviously)

This is where it gets tricky for me. I've tried adjusting the paths in the public_html/mysite.com/laravel/index.php file, but the **DIR** method/command seems to be grabbing from the wrong directory and I get the following errors:

Warning: require(/home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/../../laravelapp/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/index.php on line 22

Warning: require(/home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/../../laravelapp/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/../../laravelapp/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php71/lib/php') in /home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/index.php on line 22

Do note that I've tried modifying to document root by trying it with a subdomain, but ran into the same type of errors.

Also note that when I put the entire app (including public) inside a folder inside the addon domain (ex.: mysite.com/testing), I was able to get things working, but the images and styles would not load. I know this is a security risk, so I'm trying to do it the correct way now and get everything running smoothly.

Some help here would be greatly appreciated - been on this for 2 days now. Thanks a lot! Sorry for any redundancy here.

Edit: I've also tried modifying my path in the server.php (this was suggested on another solution) to "../public_html/mysite.com/laravel/index.php" and to no avail as well.

Answer (score 1):

You said you put your app on the same level as public_html. That means on /home1/username but you only use two .. which maps to /home1/username/public_html

You should use it three times /home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/../../../

Comment: require __DIR__.'/../../../laravelapp/bootstrap/autoload.php';  - it should look like this?

Comment: I tried this in index.php and i get the same result(s). What should I be using for the absolute path to this?

Comment: require ' /home1/username/laravelapp/bootstrap/autoload.php';

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. Should I omit the "__DIR__" or no?

Comment: Update: tried using absolute paths and now I get:
Warning: require(/home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/home1/username/laravelapp/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/username/public_html/mysite.com/laravel/index.php on line 22

Comment: Yeah omit the DIR and make sure no typos :v

Comment: Thanks. Will try with the DIR omitted. Will this effect anything in my overall app here by omitting it?

Comment: Ok so I changed to absolute paths and omitted the DIR. Installed the app via composer install - and hooked up the env file for the database. However now, all images and css are 404'd

It seems they are trying to grab from mysite.com/assets - which it should be looking for them in mysite.com/laravel/assets

Comment: How can I get it to grab from the correct directory(s)?